# Parse Server: REST-API-Key Authentication does not work

Tags: ios, authentication, parse-platform, parse-server

I configured my parse server as following:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
    cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
    appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    clientKey: process.env.CLIENT_KEY || 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    restAPIKey: process.env.RESTAPI_KEY || 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!

    ...

    serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'https://myserver.com:1337'  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
});
```

Sending a push message with the master key specified works:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
  -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "where": {
          "deviceType": {
            "$in": [
              "ios"
            ]
          }
        },
        "data": {
          "title": "The Shining",
          "alert": "All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy."
        }
      }'\   https://myserver.com/parse/push
```

However if I only provide the rest api key, it does not work.

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "where": {
          "deviceType": {
            "$in": [
              "ios"
            ]
          }
        },
        "data": {
          "title": "The Shining",
          "alert": "All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy."
        }
      }'\   https://myserver.com/parse/push
```

What is wrong with my server configuration? I thought it should work with the rest API key as soon as I define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the RESTAPI key from your configuration because it is not required, at this moment **you have to use Master key for sending Push** Notifications. You can define cloud code function that you will run from REST so you wont have to send the master key over network [Answer on Github](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/736)

Answer (score 1):

You must try /classes/

http**s**://myserver.com/parse/**classes**/push

Request this URL and dont miss to add

- "X-Parse-Application-Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
- "X-Parse-Master-Key:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
- "Content-Type: application/json"

headers and check if you re using http or https.